# Print page view in a scrolling contents in a webpage

Tags: html, printing

I have a page with multiple scrolling slides inside a pane. Whenever I try to print the second slide, it always prints the first one which is loaded when user first visit the site. Is there any print function in Javascript or JQuery, which allows me to print slides which wasn't loaded first or even the contents that is visible to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `@media print { }` and `@media screen { }` in CSS?

The first will be implemented when printing, the 2nd will be implemented on screen.

Purely as an example...

```
@media print {
   #myDiv { overflow : auto; }
}

@media screen {
   #myDiv { overflow : scroll; }
}
```

Comment: http://s10.postimage.org/8kc8jhywp/for_Stack.png, this is how my slides look on the webpage.

Comment: Sorry @Interfaith, but what are you trying to show? I'm just giving you an option of what you can try - giving me a screen shot means nothing to me

Comment: No need to apologize. What I was trying to point out was those are two of the slides on the page. When I print, no matter what slides is in view, it always prints the default one that user sees when they visit the site. Is there a print feature which will print the current view?

Comment: @Interfaith, I would have thought the print would give you the current view, but could easily believe it "reset" to the initial page.. although I would expect DOM elements that have been set to particular display settings to be as you set them.  Sorry, can't help

Comment: Well thank you for trying. Let's see if anyone else knows how to continue your effort.